# Continuable if error is null

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, node.js, error-handling

I made a method that I can use to avoid having to handle errors from callbacks.
What it does is, call the passed method only if the first argument is null.
So essentially it will bypass to the last method, if an error occurs.

Feedback is welcome.

```
/**
 * continueIf
 *
 * Returns a continuation method that only continues
 * if error is null'ish
 *
 * @param fn The function to call
 * @param args* Any number of arguments to pass after the arguments from the function
 */

function continueIf (fn) {
  var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1);
  var callback = arguments[arguments.length - 1];
  if (typeof callback !== 'function') {
    throw('Missing callback');
  }
  return function (err) {
    if (err) {
      return callback(err);
    }
    return fn.apply(null, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1).concat(args));
  };
};
```

A test case:

```
it('continues to f2 but not to f3', function (done) {
  var msg = 'hello';
  var msgErr = 'some error';
  function f1 (a, callback) {
    expect(a).toBe(msg);
    callback(null, a);
  }
  function f2 (a, callback) {
    expect(a).toBe(msg);
    callback(msgErr);
  }
  var dummy = jasmine.createSpy('dummy');
  f1(msg, continueIf(f2, continueIf(dummy, function (err) {
    expect(err).toBe(msgErr);
    expect(dummy).not.toHaveBeenCalled();
    done();
  })));
});
```

Comment: It's basically the same as using some of the Async library, although not as widely used and tested, just more simple.

Answer (score 1):

That is basically what promises, and monads in the general sense, do. If you take the abstraction one step forward, you can generalize the idea of a continuation into a monad interface (using the [FantasyLand](https://github.com/fantasyland/fantasy-land) spec):

```
function Cont(run) {
  this.run = run
}

Cont.of = function(a) {
  return new Cont(function(next) {
    next(a)
  })
}

Cont.error = function(msg) {
  return new Cont(function(_, error) {
    error(msg)
  })
}

Cont.prototype.chain = function(f) {
  return new Cont(function(next, error) {
    return this.run(function(a) {
      return f(a).run(next, error)
    }, error)
  }.bind(this))
}
```

Now your functions would have to return objects in that monad:

```
var msg = 'hello'
var msgErr = 'some error'

function f1(a) {
  console.log('f1', a === msg)
  return Cont.of(a)
}

function f2(a) {
  console.log('f2', a === msg)
  return Cont.error(msgErr)
}

// won't execute
function dummy() {
  console.log('dummy')
}
```

Then you can chain the continuations, and run the final computation, providing a callback for the success case, and an optional callback for the error case:

```
var chain = f1(msg).chain(f2).chain(dummy)

// chain.run(success, error)
chain.run(console.log, console.log)
// f1, true
// f2, true
// some error
```

Once you have this in place you can abstract regular callback-based functions to use the monad:

```
var cc = function(f) {
  return function() {
    var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments)
    var cb = f.bind.apply(f, [null].concat(args))
    return new Cont(function(next, error) {
      cb(function(err, value) {
        if (err) return error(err)
        next(value)
      })
    })
  }
}

function f1(a, cb) {
  console.log('f1', a === msg)
  cb(null, a)
}

function f2(a, cb) {
  console.log('f2', a === msg)
  cb(msgErr)
}

var chain = cc(f1)(msg).chain(cc(f2)).chain(cc(dummy))

chain.run(console.log, console.log)
// f1, true
// f2, true
// some error
```

Of course you could apply `cc` as a decorator, instead of inline:

```
var f1 = cc(function(a, cb) {
  console.log('f1', a === msg)
  cb(null, a)
})

var f2 = cc(function(a, cb) {
  console.log('f2', a === msg)
  cb(msgError)
})
```

Comment: Great, good to know it is a common approuch.